# Calculating instances beteen two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What would be the best way to calculate the longest number of consecutive "k"s in the table below in excel? I don't just want to count the total number of "k"s, I want to work out the longest string of "k"s in a row between "c"s (e.g. row 1 and 2 will both be "4"). Thanks in advance!

[image: Table 1]

Comment: Is it possible that the `k` is followed by `u`?  Is sequence `u u k k k u u` possible to appear and the answer should be 0 for example?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not averse to using VBA, you can use regular expressions.
The UDF below allows you to enter either a string, or a range of cells, as the argument.

It looks for the `ck` sequence followed by any number of `k`'s and then followed by a `c` and returns the length of the maximum length (-1 to account for the leading `c`) substring that matches

```
Option Explicit
Function CountCKKC(myData) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "ck{1,}(?=c)"
    Dim s As String, c As Range
    Dim L As Long

Select Case TypeName(myData)
    Case "Range"
        s = ""
        For Each c In myData
            s = s & c.Value2
        Next c
    Case "String"
        s = myData
    Case Else
        Debug.Print TypeName(myData)
        Stop
End Select

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    If .Test(s) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(s)
        For Each M In MC
            L = IIf((M.Length - 1) > L, M.Length - 1, L)
        Next M
    End If
End With

CountCKKC = L

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need an extra row of intermediary calculations, but its not that complicated,

a simple if and a counter :

```
=IF(B$2="k",1,0)+A$2
```

Where

```
 A2 = 0
```

Then at the final row cell, you should max the range:

```
=MAX(B2:B10)
```

Comment: oops, I don't think this would work. Maybe you should insert a row and type the formula in `Row# 3`. Let `A3 = 0`, and `B3 = IF(B2="k",1+A3,0)`. Then the last cell is `=MAX(B3:N3)`

Comment: I didn't understand your fix suggestion

Comment: OK then, can you show me how does your formula work? I'm a little bit confused. Are you filling the formula in `B2:B10`? Then every formula is a `IF()` plus `A$2`, that is 0. How do you get the answer `4`?

Comment: not a$2.. the $ is before the row, not the column, so the the 2nd cell will not add a$2 but b$2 and so on... the counter will not zero as long as the k-s are consecutive

Comment: What is inside `B2`? Data to be checked with "k" or the formula?

Comment: If you need `A$2` to become `B$2` in the next cell, then the `MAX` formula should be in `B2:N2`. However `Row#2` is the OP's data, so I commented that maybe we should insert a new row and put all the formulas in `Row#3`

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in one cell, it'll be a little bit complicated. Check this out.

```
=MAX(--((COLUMN($B2:$N2)-(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B2:$N2)))+1)=
         COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R"&ROW($B2)&"C"&TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B2:$N2))&
                          ":R"&ROW($B2)&"C"&COLUMN($B2:$N2),FALSE),"k"))*
        (COLUMN($B2:$N2)-(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B2:$N2)))+1))
```

This is an **Array Formula** so please press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** to complete it. You will see a `{}` outside the formula once you succeeded.

The key is : the max consecutive number of "k"s, which starts from `rngA` to `rngB`, is equal to the cells counted from `rngA` to `rngB`. So I built up a n*n matrix to check 1. the cells number and 2. the "k"s number.

**Warnings:** It is a n*n matrix, so if you feed too many data like 10000 columns, it may be super slow.

[image]

Comment: I found that I might be wrong :/ I didn't notice the condition of `c`. The formula works to find the longest consecutive "k"s but without checking `c`.

Comment: If your the "k" always between 2 "c"s, my formula is still correct though.

Answer (score 0):

A udf for the sheet using a regex. You pass a single row range as the first argument, `rng`,  and the letter that goes on either side as the `boundingLetter`, and the letter that goes inside as the `targetLetter.` You wanted to count "k"s between "c"s. So, "k" would be the `targetLetter` and "c" the `boundingLetter`. As they are passed as parameters you can easily change these.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim boundingLetter As String, targetLetter As String, rng As Range

    Set rng = [C2:V2]
    boundingLetter = "c"
    targetLetter = "k"

    Debug.Print GetMaxSequence(rng, boundingLetter, targetLetter)
End Sub

Public Function GetMaxSequence(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal boundingLetter As String, ByVal targetLetter As String) As Variant
    Dim arr(), matches As Object, iMatch As Object, inputString As String, finalString As String, maxLength As Long

    If rng.Count < 3 Or rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        GetMaxSequence = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    arr = rng.Value
    arr = Application.Index(arr, 1, 0)

    If IsError(arr) Then
        GetMaxSequence = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    inputString = Join(arr, Chr$(44))

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = boundingLetter & ",(" & targetLetter & ",)+" & boundingLetter

        If .Test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                If Len(iMatch) > maxLength Then
                    maxLength = Len(iMatch)
                    finalString = iMatch
                End If
            Next iMatch
        Else
            GetMaxSequence = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            Exit Function
        End If
        .Pattern = boundingLetter & "|,"
        GetMaxSequence = Len(.Replace(finalString, vbNullString))
    End With
End Function
```

---

In  sheet:

[image]

Comment: Your solution returns `2` for the sequence `ckkckkkkkkkcabcde`

Answer (score 0):

OK I was wrong, it isn't so easy to use the Frequency function.

You would at least have to ignore any k's left over at each end of the range (these are not enclosed by c's):

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:M2="k",COLUMN(B2:M2)),IF(B2:M2="c",COLUMN(B2:M2)))*(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(B2:M2,"c")+1))>1)*(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(B2:M2,"c")+1))<=COUNTIF(B2:M2,"c")))
```

which is an array formula.

[image]

Then if you wanted to ignore k's that were between c's but were interspersed with other characters (like 'u'), would need another condition:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B4:M4="k",COLUMN(B4:M4)),IF(B4:M4="c",COLUMN(B4:M4)))
*(FREQUENCY(IF(B4:M4<>"k",COLUMN(B4:M4)),IF(B4:M4="c",COLUMN(B4:M4)))=1)
*(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(B4:M4,"c")+1))>1)* 
(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(B4:M4,"c")+1))<=COUNTIF(B4:M4,"c")))
```

The '=1' in the second line of the formula is because <>"k" includes "c", so you would always get at least one count.

[image]

Comment: No, I just realised this myself, so I will delete it for now.